# PIP Python LinkedIn

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api, pip, ipython

I have installed the LinkedIn using pip. However, when I'm calling for an import it acts as if it is not there, it doesn't recognize it as a module.

What could I be doing that is wrong?

```
In [59]: !pip install LinkedIn
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): LinkedIn in c:\users\o
wner\anaconda\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in c:\users\o
wner\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from LinkedIn)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauth2 in c:\users\own
er\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from LinkedIn)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson in c:\users
\owner\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from LinkedIn)
Cleaning up...

In [60]: from LinkedIn import LinkedIn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-9e394099ee12> in <module>()
----> 1 from LinkedIn import LinkedIn

ImportError: No module named LinkedIn
```

Comment: Is it `from linkedin import LinkedIn`? Module names are generally lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Github repo](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/linkedin), the module is in lowercase. Also, there's no `LinkedIn` class/variable in the module. I think you want the API:

```
from linkedin import LinkedinAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lack of values in the system variables:
After pip install, you can append the repository of the package "linkedin" installed in the "Path" system variable, which is, in my case, C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages